# Файл из ресурсов недоступен при запуске jar

Tags: java

Есть проект, нормально запускается в IDEA, но при создании jar файла он просто не запускается, а при попытке запустить через консоль при помощи java -jar путь_до_файла\файл.jar выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\final_count.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    at com.my.projects.SpaceObjectsTest.main(SpaceObjects.java:57)
```

Программа использует 3  текстовых файла, один из которых почему-то не может найти, хотя при составлении структуры проекта я все закинул в jar (пробовал разархивировать и посмотреть, правда ли они там есть - есть). Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Также выкладываю содержимое MANIFEST.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: myprojects.SpaceObjectsTest
```

В самом коде путь до файла указал так:

```
"/final_count.txt"
```

Comment: А разве в вашем случае локальные файлы, такие как final_count.txt должны лежать не рядом с jar файлом? Они вроде как не могут быть получены из jar-ника потом.

Comment: Пробовал положить все файлы в одну папку с jar файлом - то же самое.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что нужно рядом с .jar воссоздать такой путь **resources\final_count.txt**, хотя возможно я не прав.

Comment: Да, я так и пробовал, но ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из стектрейса видно, что используется доступ к файлу по имени `resources\final_count.txt`. Когда процесс пробует открыть файл по относительному пути, то это путь ищется относительно текущей рабочей директории процесса (в java насколько мне известно [нельзя](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4045688) поменять текущую рабочую директорию).

При запуске командой `java -jar путь_до_файла\файл.jar` текущей рабочей директорией будет та из которой запускается команда `java` т.е. первая директория в `путь_до_файла`. Соответственно, программа будет искать файл в каталоге `resources` текущего каталога. Именно поэтому у вас не работает, когда вы помещаете файл относительно каталога в котором находится `файл.jar`.

Чтобы можно было достать файл именно из jar, нужно открывать его не с помощью API доступа к файловой системе типа `FileReader`, а используя `getResource` или `getResourceAsStream` у класса `ClassLoader`. Например, если вы положили файл в корень `jar` файла, то получить поток можно так:

```
try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
            this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/final_count.txt")) {
   // используем isr точно так же как и FileReader
}
```

Если положить файл в какую-то папку внутри `фай.jar` файла, то нужно указать полный путь от корня jar файла.