# Не читается файл типа properties внутри jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

**maven pop.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>akus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

*структура проекта*

```
progect
    >.idea
    >out
    >src
        >>main
                >java
                    Main
                    myPropery.properties    
    >resources
        >>test
    >target
```

*класс Main*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String properdy_address = "src/main/java/myProperty.properties";
        Properties myProperty = new Properties();
        File file = new File(properdy_address);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        myProperty.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(myProperty.getProperty("user1"));
        System.out.println(myProperty.getProperty("user2"));
        System.out.println(myProperty.getProperty("user3"));
    }
}
```

[image: Текст ошибки]

Comment: смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1279699/218971 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1212584/218971

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Я не понимаю. Этот вопрос выделяется (в лучшую сторону) из других, в нем есть минмальный и воспроизводимый пример. Да, есть скриншот вместо текста ошибки, это бы подправить, но в остальном - все нормально. Чего вам не хватает?

Comment: файл  проперти не должен лежать вместе с классами, как у вас, аа должен быть в папке ресурсов

Comment: Положите файл `в src/resources` и читайте через поток: `RailflowStatisticsCollector.class.getResourceAsStream("myProperty.properties");`